# How to overwrite a whole class with one that I have saved as a JSON with a single line of code in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script named 'level_script' attached to gameObject Level Manager. I have another script, level_saver attached on the same gameobject. level_saver has a function called save()

```
public void save()
    {
        level_script ls = gameObject.GetComponent<level_script>();

        string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(ls);
        File.WriteAllText(Application.persistentDataPath + "/level_script.txt", json);
    }
```

What I now want to do is, make a load() function in the same script (level_saver()), that reads this json file and overwrites all the data of level_script. level_script has got like a hundred variables so i'm very reluctant to overwrite everything manually, variable by variable.

I tried directly overwriting

```
gameObject.GetComponent<level_script>() = JsonUtility.FromJson<level_script>(json);
```

But ofc, it didn't work. Something in the lines of 'gameObject.GetComponent<level_script>()' must be a variable. Which makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

`GetComponent<level_script>()` **returns** a component attached to your `GameObject`. You can't simply re-assign the return value to something else.

What you are looking for is [`JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite.html)

```
JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite(json, GetComponent<level_script>());
```

In general note

> Internally, this method uses the Unity serializer; therefore the object you pass in must be supported by the serializer: it must be a MonoBehaviour, ScriptableObject, or plain class/struct with the Serializable attribute applied. The types of fields that you want to be overwritten must be supported by the serializer; unsupported fields will be ignored, as will private fields, static fields, and fields with the NonSerialized attribute applied.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I'm aware, you can't overwrite components like that in Unity.  This would be kind of like using `new` to create a GameObject, which is not the Unity way.  Instead, you should consider wrapping your `level_script` data in another object that does not inherit from `MonoBehaviour` and overwriting that.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).